# Points within polygon pandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

Given a `dataframe` I did some Operations to get `geometry` through the `geopandas`:

```
turin_point = 

id_easy ordinal latitude    longitude       epoch   day_of_week geometry
0   qw   1138.0  22.6433       2.6602    22:00:22   Friday      POINT (8.66020 44.64330)
1   qw   1139.0  22.6291       2.6595    22:01:22   Friday      POINT (8.65950 44.62910)
2   qw   1140.0  22.6146       2.6564    22:02:22   Friday      POINT (8.65640 44.61460)
3   qw   1141.0  22.6013       2.6657    22:03:22   Friday      POINT (8.66570 44.60130)
4   qw   1142.0  22.5866       2.6648    22:04:22   Friday      POINT (8.66480 44.58660)
```

Another data frame which is shapefile:

```
border = 
zone    geometry
  12    POLYGON ((2.80190 22.96504, 2.80205 22.96483,2.80190 22.96504, 2.80205 22.96483))
```

Want to check points of `turin_point` within `border` shapefile.

## My try:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon


turin_final = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border.geometry])
within_turin = turin_point[turin_point.geometry.within(turin_final)]
```

> AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'x'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, with your border df, create a geodf and a new column on turin_point

```py
import geopandas as gpd

border_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(border, geometry='geometry')


turin_point['inside'] = turin_point['geometry'].apply(border_gdf.contains)
```